# How to check if OpenCV is correctly installed on MacOSX Snow Leopard

Tags: opencv, osx-snow-leopard

I don't know How to be sure that OpenCV is installed on my MacOSX Snow Leopard ? 
Where am I supposed to look ? Is there a specific framework ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how you're building and installing OpenCV, but for me the headers are at: `/usr/local/include/opencv`, e.g. `/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h` and the libraries are at `/usr/local/lib`, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/libcv.1.0.0.dylib`.